# Nothing being written to "Trace Information" section in trace file

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to debug a web service running on asp.net 4.0 website

This is what my web.config section looks like

```
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
```

The myService.svc file in the webdirectory looks like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" Debug="true"  Service="myService" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/myService.vb" %>
```

If I look at and clear the trace at:

```
http://myserver.com/service/Trace.axd
```

Like this:

[image]

It is there and then I call the service from a client (which errors) but I can see a new record appear in the trace list like this:

[image]

I can see it has status 500.  Yes I know it has errored. So the I click into it.

And yet the trace information section as nothing in it.

[image]

Yet I have placed trace commands in the code like this:

```
   Trace.Write("I am Starting!!")
```

I lost.  Please help.

Comment: You are certain your trace line is being hit prior to the exception being thrown?

Comment: Yes, the service only error when some combination of parameters is entered.  If I send some other parameters, it does not error, it completes. But still no tracing lines written.